# TakePicture Launcher only works first time after ask for permission on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera-intent

I have to send a image with Retrofit MultiPart. So I show a dialog to select from gallery or Camera. Gallery works.

On camera I have a problem cause **only works after ask for permission**. For example if I have my camera permission accepted, then I can launch the camera and get the URI (when I do a `.exist` is `true` but the Content-Length is 0.

But if I show the permission dialog. ONLY this time works.

My launcher:

```
  val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) {
    if (it && uri.path?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
        viewmodel.onImageUpdated(uri)
    }
}
```

To create the URI and temp file:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val file = context.createImageFile()
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    Objects.requireNonNull(context), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file
)

fun Context.createImageFile(): File {
val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
return File.createTempFile(
    imageFileName, 
    ".jpg", 
    externalCacheDir
)
```

}

My Manifest

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/path_provider" />
    </provider>
```

And path provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-cache-path name="my_images" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

Now, when user select camera I just call -> (Case when file doesnt work):

```
    val permissionCheckResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            )
            if (permissionCheckResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
            } else {
                permissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            }
```

If user havent permission -> this works:

```
val permissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
) {
    if (it) {
        cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

I really don't know wha's wrong because its the same function.

RESUME:

When I call cameraLauncher after accept camera permission the URI contain the image. If I do with the permission accepted the URI doesnt contain the image.

Comment: `context.createImageFile()` Do not create an empty file yourself. If the user cancels the picture you are left with an empty file. You only need a File class instance not a real file.

Comment: It is unclear when you create te uri. Do it everytime just before the launch.

Comment: Further it is unclear what goes wrong. Which errors or exceptions? Logcat?

Comment: No error, I just receive a valid uri, but when I call context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) is empty

Comment: Yes that can happen. Quite normal. As soon as the camera app is on top of your activity or your activity is not the top one your activity can be killed and hence the uri value has gone.

Comment: And why do you say that the launcher only works the first time? The launcher works perfectly.. You should only say that your uri has gone. Know what happens.

Comment: Build up the File and uri instance directly before the launch. It is unclear where and when you do it now.

Comment: I tried and doesnt work. But follow your tip I just include a remember{} on my URI and file and works!

Answer (score 0):

Finally and thank to @blackapps I found a solution.

I think the problem was the recomposition. To fix that I just include a remember on my Uri and File

```
val file = remember { context.createImageFile() }
val uri = remember {
    FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        Objects.requireNonNull(context), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file
    )
}
```